# iOS 5.1: Getting "CoreData: error: (21)" on NSManagedObjectContext save

Tags: exception, core-data, ios5

There's an application I've had handed down to me that shows PDFs, and stores rotation angle and zoom state when closing the PDF.

The symptom I'm encountering is on `[NSManagedObjectContext save]` I get:

**CoreData: error: (21) I/O error for database at *path to db*
SQLite error code:21, 'unable to open database file'
2012-03-06 09:58:40.227 Navtech iCharts[59838:fb03] The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 21.)**

This only occurs after about 225-250 saves.  After it occurs, the app can't even open `.nib` files, thus resulting in:

**'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle**

I looked up the sqlite documentation on the error and found only the header:

```
#define SQLITE_MISUSE      21   /* Library used incorrectly */
```

I'm not even sure where to begin diagnosing this.  Does anyone know what would cause this to occur so consistently yet so infrequently?

---

For context, here's the code that executes the save:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.context];
NSError *err = nil;
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (![self.context save:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.context];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running out of file descriptors. Are you (directly and/or indirectly) opening a lot of files?

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589485/core-data-updating-max-pk-failed=), too.

Comment: We are opening a lot of files directly (not sure about indirectly).  A few hundred before the bug happens.  Perhaps we're not releasing them correctly.  I'll take a look.  Thanks

Comment: You should try to limit this. There's a hard limit to the number of files you can have open.

Comment: We had been using a bunch of `fopen`s.  I didn't get a chance to determine whether we were releasing them properly because another developer had removed the `fopen`s with streams in the mean time.  This definitely lends a lot of weight to your hypothesis.