# Receiving errors when try to insert a lot of data into database using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite, core-data

I have troubles with storing data into database using Core Data. Here an error I receive:

```
Core Data: annotation: -executeRequest: encountered exception = I/O error for database at /usr/local/mydatabase.sqlite.  SQLite error code:21, 'unable to open database file' with userInfo = {
    NSFilePath = "/usr/local/mydatabase.sqlite";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 21;
}
Core Data: annotation: -executeRequest: encountered exception = Updating max pk failed:  with userInfo = {
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
}
```

My application launching in background and stores a lot of data into database.(5000 records per day) 
After 3-4 days I receive errors above every time I try to insert data.
But if I insert data (e.g. 2000k) in a row in loop it works well.

Here is a code I do storing:

```
-(bool)storeData:(NSString *)data
{
    [lock tryLock];

    BOOL success = NO;

    @autoreleasepool {

        Message* message = (Message*)[Message insertInManagedObjectContext:moc];
        message.data = data;

        NSError *obtainError = nil;

        NSArray *objArr = [[moc registeredObjects] allObjects];
        [moc obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:objArr error:&obtainError];

        if (obtainError != nil) {

            NSLog(@"%s database obtain error: %@", __FUNCTION__, obtainError);
        }

        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([moc save:&error]) {

            success = YES;
        }

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%s database error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
        }

        for (NSManagedObject *mo in [moc registeredObjects]) {
            [moc refreshObject:mo mergeChanges:NO];
        }

        [moc reset];
    }

    return success;

    [lock unlock];
}
```

I was looking to that topic but it's not so informative and useful for me:
[Core Data: Updating max pk failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589485/core-data-updating-max-pk-failed)

Answer (score 1):

5,000 records isn't a lot of data.  However it is a lot of file handles.  I would not recommend doing `-obtainPermanentIDsForObjects: error:` on that many objects and in fact you don't need to do that at all.  Especially since you are following it with a save.  Remove that call, save your import frequently and you should avoid that issue.